# Is there a way to hide the header response value "server: awselb/2.0" from AWS ALB?

Tags: http-headers, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I'm using AWS ALB for my application and when we did the AppSec testing, it shows that the header response with the value "server: awselb/2.0" as a security threat. That means, if there is a vulnerability or zero day detected on AWS ALB, these details from a server can be used, and its a threat.

Is there a way to hide this server response? If it's an option on ALB or if we need to use a WAF rule for that, it all works. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to 10 month old answers in https://repost.aws/questions/QU41Jdv5awSnq9rda-zbNhrQ/how-can-i-remove-aswelb-2-0-in-the-http-response-header, there isn't a config option on the ELB to remove that header.

A possible workaround is to put a CDN in front of the ELB to filter the response headers.